# How can I export a font file from Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, export, font-management

If a person or a designer wants to export a font file from Adobe Illustrator, how can he or she so do to make it a TTF or OTF file?

Comment: The short answer is that you can't. If you are designing a font in Illustrator then you will need additional software to turn your drawings of characters into an actual working font.

Comment: I have not used yet, but there's this: https://www.fontself.com/ (which is in the group of answers via the link at top of this question)

Comment: If your question is how to turn your vectors into a font file, you can try an extension dedicated for that: Fontself Maker  (https://www.fontself.com). It directly runs into Illustrator (and Photoshop) and lets you export font files.

Answer (score 1):

As alredy commented, a piece of font editing software inputs your Ai file (or clipboard) and places it as a glyph into a font. There are Fontographer, Type Tool etc... as examples of commercial products. Free font editing software is also available.

Font editing software is complex and often it's well underestimated, how much effort it takes to create a proper complete font. If you're fast and accurate in Ai, that surely speeds the font creation process. Vector drawing and editing tools in font editors are rudimentary when compared to Ai.

Your question can have also another answer. You may want to copy a complete font that is available in Ai, but cannot be found in the Fonts folder of your system. This is because commercial font suppliers, for example Adobe put a substantial amount of effort to prevent users to distribute their fonts or to use them without paying the wanted price.

In that case you should buy or hire the font for use in the system to where you originally wanted to copy the font.

Note: Adobe CC stuff should be available for you in two of your computers, but  not simultaneously, if you pay only for one license. You can install the CC stuff for ex. into your desktop workststion and into your laptop or tablet.

Comment: I  want to be able to export those fonts to TTF or OTF file format. Hence, I’m not looking for a software, but only for a plug-in for AICC. because we are already able to draw the alphabets in Ai. what i wanna know is if there is some sort of plug-in for Adobe Illustrator which can convert my alphabets in to a font file (ttf or otf)                         I also want to follow these trends for 2017, The font trend and all https://www.pixelslogodesign.com/blog/trends-follow-2017-creating-logo-business/

Comment: @user94361 Font is much more than the drawn glyphs. For example, the numeric character codes, the positions of the glyphs, the space between them, possible kerning and the hinting for readable low resolution output. A font file has so much additional data that Font editor programs are developed to manage it all as easily as possible. Note: Plugins also are software, only limited to get their input from the host program and often without a possiblity to save the result elsewhere than into the current artboard of the host. If it MUST be a plugin, check Fontself: https://www.fontself.com/

Comment: Works for me, Thank you so much :) sorry for the delay response. winter is here.